# where is Visual Studio.Uml.extension.dll for code generation in visual studio 2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

when trying text template there is a line 
import Visual Studio.Uml.extension.dll

but reference add can not find this dll. where is it?

Answer (score 1):

This was changed in RC to Microsoft.VisualStudio.ArchitectureTools.Extensibility.dll. The docs for it are here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee517354%28VS.100%29.aspx

Hope that helps